# What is VPS provisioning?

Tags: vps, provisioning

I'm starting to get my feet wet in the VPS world, so I have some newbie questions for you gurus.

The first is this (as title): **what is VPS provisioning**?

When you do it and what it's useful for?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the manual, semi-automated or fully-automated creation of the storage, networking, VM creation/cloning, OS configuration and user communication of a fully fledged virtual server to order. It's often initiated either directly by a web store front-end or some form of post-purchase operations-led interface.

Basically it's the means to go from a single "build me a VPS" click to handing it over to the user fully ready with as little time and cost incurred as possible.

These systems are often just scripted chains of events utilising APIs from storage and networking vendors with large chunks of API interaction with the hypervisor of choice. Some systems such as VMWare's Orchestrator can be both scripted and also GUI driven.

Answer (score 3):

**Provisioning** is the process of creating a new virtual server and installing an operating system on it. It's done... whenever you need a new virtual server.

Answer (score 0):

Provisioning is a process to setup a new server. It includes to installing the operating system and other system software like MSSQL server, Mail server, ControlPanel etc.., as well configuration of it to manage all domains and websites hosted on the server. Once it is configured it may assign to a particular customer for their business requirement.